# Why is perfection a good trait to have?

Tags: theology, virtue-ethics

"Better a flawed diamond than a perfect pebble." - Confucius

I think the definition of perfection is "fully actualizes its own nature." According to Christian theology, it is a good thing to be perfect. But according to Confucius and common sense (or at least the common sense of the modern Western world), it is preferable to be something of a more noble nature but imperfect, than it is to be of a base nature but perfect.

In light of this, why is perfection good?

Comment: See French poet Joseph Roux's quote: *"A fine quotation is a diamond on the finger of a man of wit, and a pebble in the hand of a fool."* Indeed according to Plato the Good is the supreme perfect form above all other forms, such as evil, wealth, number, geometry, etc. Here Confucius's so-called perfect pebble is not the *literal* perfection as you intended and interpreted, but only a relative conception from the perspective of the fools...

Comment: @DoubleKnot I wasn't thinking about the parody argument "the most perfect island" against the ontological argument when I wrote this post.

Comment: Indeed, Anselm was very flattered by Gaunilo's parody argument - he even suggested it should be published alongside his own ontological argument in future! However, he argued that the parody does not really work because you can't substitute anything you like for 'God'. Islands are contingent and God exists necessarily (aseity). Islands are created and can be destroyed. Thus sounds like those happy to live on the perfect island are fools according to Anselm's perspective...

Comment: @DoubleKnot What are the definitions of "relative perfection" and "absolute perfection"?

Comment: Suppose you never see diamond before, and there're a bunch of pebbles and one of them is "perfect" in the sense without flaws and stains. Then you may say this one pebble is perfect until one day you have the opportunity to see a flawed diamond which shines and transcends immediately aesthetically. OTOH the definition of "absolute perfection" must necessarily denote *God* (as a phonetic emphasis of the supreme *good*) if it exists...

Comment: @DoubleKnot That sounds like the difference between local optima and global optima in mathematics.

Comment: So it is, so it is, except the existence and uniqueness of *the* global optima is yet to be proved which is the famous [ontological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontological_argument), famous mathematicians such as Godel tried too as referenced...

Comment: @DoubleKnot what do you think of the ontological argument?

Comment: I sincerely recommend you act as if God so defined exists since it's actually all about ethics even if it cannot be proved, otherwise you may encounter confusion, depression, anxiety, nostalge, etc, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that is a saying from Confucius. Nowhere online is it attributed in the Analects or elsewhere. Confucius is probably the most misattributed source for quotes. In this case it's extra obvious, because in ancient China they used diamond as a tool, and not as far as I can find for jewelry. Their paragon material was jade, in large part because of Confucius' commentary on what made the best quality pieces of it.

I would counterpoint with a version of the Italian proverb:

> "Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good."

And

> "There is no excellent beauty that hath not some strangeness in the
> proportion." -Francis Bacon

For a diamond, perfection can be defined, it is a [paragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragon_(diamond)), a large flawless crystal without inclusions.

You say "fully actualizes its own nature" is perfection for humans. But how can we know what that is? If you look at how Aristotle frames this, as the human telos, it is open-ended and about maximising our scope to express ourselves and adapt. That is, it's a personal moment-by-moment evaluation.

In Zen they say 'Water that is too clear, has no fishes'. To be a paragon, to make the water too clear, is to turn away from life, from risks, from change. We are not rocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are offering an argument (inductive, I think, so over hasty), then I have to disagree with my reconstruction of it.

1. Nobility is best
2. Nobility cannot be perfected
3. So nothing perfect is good

I suppose some teleological claim might be implicit in it: that we all aim at what is best, and only it truly exists.

Myself, I'm not super sympathetic. The problems with a perfection should be worked out internal to the thing that has been perfected.